# AS3 When symbol is in a certain position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using Flash Professional CS5.5 and I need to make an app where there is a ball (symbol) that moves using the accelerometer and I want that, when the ball A coordinates reach this coordinates B I go to frame 2 (gotoAndPlay(2)). I have to find the ball coord first, right?
How do I make this?

Here is the code I've now

```
c_ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);
function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void{
c_ball.startDrag();}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);
function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void{
c_ball.stopDrag();}
```

would it work if, after retriving the coordinates?

```
function f_level (e) if (c_ball.x==100 && c_ball.y==100) {
gotoAndStop(2);}
```

Comment: What have you already coded? The movement of the ball?

Comment: Yes, the moviment of the ball, using both accelerometer or drag&drop

Comment: Could you please put some of your code here to help people find what is left to be done and where to put this feature. Did you write this code yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Collision detection creating a targetarea and test it with your ball - object if wanted onEnterframe or when every you thing its time:

```
private function test():void{
    if(  ball.hitTestObject(testarea) ){
        // here goes next frame command ;)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add an `enter frame` event listener, and check the coordinates of c_ball there.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, siteLoop);

public function siteLoop(event:Event)
{
  if ((c_ball.x > 99.9) && (c_ball.y > 99.9)){
    gotoAndStop(2);
  }
}
```